# Validate if commit exists

Tags: git, scripting, githooks

How to validate whether the commit with given sha exists in current branch?

There are many ways to parse outputs, but I need optimal way which returns boolean (for usage in bash script).

e.g.

```
sha=$1
if [ -z `git magic --validate $sha` ]; then
  echo "Invalid commit sha: $sha"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if one commit is an ancestor of another commit (or vice-versa)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345157/how-can-i-tell-if-one-commit-is-an-ancestor-of-another-commit-or-vice-versa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rev-list | grep` method works fine; there's the tiniest bit of overhead because git has to print out all the SHA1s for `grep` to see, but it's not really a big deal.

You can also do it with `git merge-base` if you like - if the merge base of the target commit and the branch is the target commit, the branch contains the target commit:

```
if [ "$(git merge-base $commit $branch)" = "$commit" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Either way you do it, note that `rev-list` and `merge-base` are going to be printing out SHA1s, so if the commit you're testing for inclusion is named by a branch or tag, you'll want to use `git rev-parse` to turn it into an SHA1 first.

Comment: Just a tiny note:  the POSIX string equally operator is `=`, not `==`.  bash will accept both anyway.

Comment: @Sven: Thanks, I always forget that.

Comment: For a small optimization, it's useful to use `git rev-list -qn1 <commit> 2>/dev/null`, which won't traverse the whole commit tree and will exit with a non-zero exit code if the given commit does not exist.

Comment: @nvie If you're trying to verify the existence of a commit, I think the canonical way is `git rev-parse --quiet --verify <commit>`.

Answer (score 25):

```
git rev-parse --quiet --verify <commit>
```

Does not actually verify that commit (I guess SHA1 is what is meant) exists. It verifies that there is an object in the database corresponding to the SHA1 provided. That is, if there is a blob or tree object that matches the SHA1, it will report that it exists, even if it is not a commit.

```
git rev-parse --quiet --verify <sha1>^{commit}
```

This will verify that the object exists and that it is an object that can be used as a commit (commit or annotated tag).

Comment: But this does not limit findings to the current branch as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the output of

```
git rev-list HEAD..$sha
```

If this command fails because the sha1 does not exist at all in the repository, the exit code will be non-zero.  If the output is empty, the commit is in the current branch, and if it is non-empty, it is not.  So your script would look like

```
if revlist=`git rev-list HEAD..$sha 2>/dev/null` && [ -z "$revlist" ]; then
    :
fi
```

In case you already know that `$sha` really names a commit (as a SHA1 hash or in any other way), this simplifies to

```
if [ -z "`git rev-list HEAD..$sha`" ]; then
    :
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

git cat-file prints information about the objects in the repository. "-e" checks if the object is valid and exits with a 0 status and when invalid exists with a 1.

```
git cat-file -e 3d68db1028afe27a0055c2234f98fc945b1958f5
echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor $sha HEAD
```

---

This tests if `$sha` is an ancestor commit for the current branch (`HEAD`), and exits successfully if it is.

In your example,

```
sha=$1
if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor $sha HEAD; then
  echo "Invalid commit sha: $sha"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This option is available since Git 1.9.0.

Comment: Correct. v1.9 has been around for about a year and half at the time of this writing.

Comment: Debian has a 2-year release cycle, and AFAIK it’s not uncommon that oldstable version is in production use. That’s why I find it necessary to state the Git version this feature was included in.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rev-list branch-youre-interested-in | grep -q sha-youre-interested-in
```

You can use the exit code from grep in conditionals.

For the current branch,

```
 git rev-list HEAD | grep -q sha-youre-interested-in
```