# git pull fails 'error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!'

Tags: git

git pull is giving this error:

```
$ git pull
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
Current branch mybranch is up to date.
```

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409320/403616) but it doesn't work for me. 
**Updated** info:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull 
trace: exec: 'git-pull'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '-u'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'branch.mybranch.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--ignore-submodules' '--refresh'
trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules'
trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--cached' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules' 'HEAD' '--'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'refs/remotes/origin/mybranch'
trace: built-in: git 'merge-base' '53512e9ce3faa7c78b6d5d7ba1a63e56b5a42a11' 'refs/heads/mybranch'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@git-master' 'git-upload-pack '\''function-test'\'''
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
trace:...
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help. But try `git remote prune origin`

Comment: please do `$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull` and update your question with the actual refspec being used to call `git fetch` (the first thing `git pull` does).

Comment: @Vimsha: ```$ git remote prune origin``` returns 
```error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!```

Comment: `git remote prune origin` worked for me!

Answer (score 52):

The simplest thing would be to completely remove your stash. Note that you’ll need to remove two files - not one file, as outlined in the linked solution:

```
rm .git/refs/stash .git/logs/refs/stash
```

Comment: rm .git/refs/... works to me, thank you @mockinterface.

Comment: had to run `git stash` after that and errors vanished

Comment: I ended up doing a text search through my entire .git directory and removing all references.

Comment: I'm on Windows with git-gui 0.21 and when I went to menu Repository -> Visualize master's history, it showed the error, but I did this and the message it's gone, hope will nevershow again

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error.  Two servers were pulling a clone from the same source; only one of them gave this error.  So I dug deeper.

Git's [release notes for version 1.8.5.5](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.5.txt#L22-L25) state:

> - "git clone" would fail to clone from a repository that has a ref
>     directly under "refs/", e.g. "refs/stash", because different
>     validation paths do different things on such a refname.  Loosen the
>     client side's validation to allow such a ref.

I found that one of the servers was using Git 1.7.1 and the other was using Git 1.8.5.6.

It's worth noting that the `fetch` command would fail as well, though not explicitly mentioned in the release notes above.

---

In my particular case I also found that the server with Git 1.7.1 actually *had* the later Git as well, but it was later in the `PATH` environment variable.

It may be of interest that when I ran `git fetch` using the later version, the clone thereafter worked *even with the older version.*

---

The simplest solution is just to **upgrade Git to version 1.8.5.5 or later.**

<sub>Or, of course, drop the stash, but then your clone will break again next time someone makes a stash.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue but while doing `go build` or `go mod tidy` or `go run`. All the commands were giving me the same errors,

'error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!'

I tried many things as below.

1. `git remote prune origin`
2. `git stash`
3. `rm .git/refs/stash .git/logs/refs/stash`

**Nothing worked for me**. Finally, I **deleted** all the cache present in my system under path `$GOPATH/go/pkg/mod/cache/`, and I was able to resolve the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the recommended solutions, but nothing fixed it. What fixed it for me at the end was pretty simple:

```bash
# Made a small change in a code-file with vim

# stash'ed it then
git stash

# got it back
git stash pop

# reverted my small change
git checkout .

# finish, no more error
git pull
```

That might not work for everyone, and it might not work without following other fixes made earlier in here. But its worth a try.