# Check if a commit is _not_ in a branch

Tags: git

I have a commit `bca7704e` that I'm pretty certain is not in `Release-1.0`. If I do `git log Release-1.0` and search, the commit doesn't show up. However, if I do `git log bca7704e` it seems to do the log for that commit without respect to the current branch (which I would expect anyway)

I can do `git branch --contains bca7704e | grep Release-1.0` as an ad-hoc check to see that the commit is not in the current branch.

However, is there any way to look for commits with respect to a given branch (or the current branch?) If the commit doesn't exist I would expect it to error out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if one commit is an ancestor of another commit (or vice-versa)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345157/how-can-i-tell-if-one-commit-is-an-ancestor-of-another-commit-or-vice-versa)

Comment: You can just `git log | grep bca7704e`