# Git - Is a commit A before or after B

Tags: git

I want to be able to understand between which 2 tags (tags which represent versions of my app) a commit is.

Is there a command for discerning if Commit A is a parent higher up the tree of commit B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding tags

You can at least know if your commit is done *after* a tag with [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe):

```
 git describe --tags
 aTagName-n-gxxxx
```

`aTagName` represents the closest tag from your current commit.
If your commit is past that tag, you won't get just its name, but `aTagName-n-gxxxx`, with `n` being the number of commits after that tag to your current commit, represented by the SHA1 `xxx`.

You can combine that with `git tag --contains <yourCommit>` in order to get the tags which includes your commit: the last one should be the oldest one whose history still include your commit.

### Regarding commits:

> Is there a command for discerning if Commit A is a parent higher up the tree of commit B.

See "[How can I tell if one commit is an ancestor of another commit (or vice-versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345268/6309)"

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <commit1> <commit2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to show it quickly is to run

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline A..B
```

and just see which tag appears first in the history.

(`oneline` is just to reduce paging in case there are lots of commits, and `decorate` is to show the tags).

---

Note (see [Specifying Ranges](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) on the form `r1..r2`) that this runs `merge-base` internally, so if you're doing this a lot, running `merge-base` directly probably *is* better ... but you need to examine the return value. You could just write a shell function, or script, and add a git alias to do it nicely:

```
function ancestor()
{
    if git merge-base --is-ancestor $1 $2; then
        echo "$1 is ancestor of $2";
    else
        if git merge-base --is-ancestor $2 $1; then
            echo "$2 is ancestor of $1";
        else
            echo "no parent-child relationship at all";
        fi;
    fi
}
```

This will also tell you if neither commit is an ancestor of the other. If you want to know which is *above* the other in that case, first decide what that means, and then choose one of the commit ordering options to git-log.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A and B are not referring to the same commit, `git merge-base A B`

If the result is A's commit, then A is an ancestor of B.

If the result is B's commit, then B is an ancestor of A.

If the result is neither A nor B, then A and B are diverged. But they have at lease one common ancestor.

If the result is empty, then A and B are from two branches and they have no common ancestor.