# What repos changed since a particluar tag?

Tags: git, github

Our organization has multiple repos.  We have common release branch names and release tags across repos.

So let's say I have a release branch called release/5.1.0.  We have created several release candidate tags from this branch.  Let's say the latest one was v5.1.0-rc.4.  This is the case for 5 different repos (they all have this same branch name and tag names).

I'd like to ask the following question to Github:

"Which of my repos have had changes to their release/5.1.0 branch since the v5.1.0-rc tag?"

or more technically:

"Which of the repos in my organization have commits in their release/5.1.0 branch that have the commit pointed to by their v5.1.0-rc.4 tag as an ancestor?"

I'd like to do this without having to check each repo individually, in as few steps as possible.

Is there an easy-ish way to do this?

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this, one of them is: `git merge-base --is-ancestor v5.1.0-rc.4 release/5.1.0 ; echo $?`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345157/how-can-i-tell-if-one-commit-is-an-ancestor-of-another-commit-or-vice-versa) answer can help you.