# How to check if the commit exists in a Git repository by its SHA-1

Tags: git

In a similar topic [Validate if commit exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127967/validate-if-commit-exists) they recommend:

```
git rev-list HEAD..$sha
```

If it exits without error code than the commit exists.

But is it efficient enough just for validation?

I was thinking about this option:

```
git cat-file commit $sha
```

Is it correct for my task and are there any other ideas?

Comment: "*But is it efficient enough just for validation?*" I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella To be more precise I am looking for the fastest approach. I want to choose the right git command to avoid time penalty.

Comment: My favorite is `git merge-base <commit> <the-same-commit> >/dev/null 2>&1`. Without the `2>&1`, it gives nice error messages, no further fiddling required.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can just run `git cat-file -t $sha` and check it returns "commit". You are right, you don't need to actually print the actual object for that...

I'm not 100% sure that what goes on behind the scene is more efficient, though.

`test $(git cat-file -t $sha) == commit`

Comment: Eventually I decided to use `git cat-file commit $sha` as it just exits with error if `$sha` does not represent a commit, so I do not need to test stdout (in my case I also need to trim it as it adds line break at the end of "commit").

Comment: Note this will also return "commit" for a branch name

Comment: Branches are not objects :) Checking whether you entered a ref or a SHA-1 can be done with rev-parse: `[[ $(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $sha) = refs/* ]]`

Answer (score 54):

```
git cat-file -e $sha^{commit}
```

---

From `git cat-file` docs:

> ```
>    -e
>       Suppress all output; instead exit with zero status if <object> exists
>       and is a valid object.
> ```

This (1) shows that this is an intended use case for `cat-file` and (2) avoids the resources of actually outputting any commit contents.

Appending `^{commit}` ensures that the object is a commit (i.e. not a tree or blob) or -- as remram points out -- resolves to a commit.

For example,

```
if git cat-file -e $sha^{commit}; then
  echo $sha exists
else
  echo $sha does not exist
fi
```

Comment: This does NOT ensure that the object is a commit, but that **it can resolve to a commit**; for instance it will work for something like a tag. `^{commit}` means to resolve to a commit, not to ensure the original object has that type. My answer makes sure it's a commit, though I'm not sure the OP cares about this distinction (his own version has the same issue as yours).

Comment: @remram, I assume that `$sha` is a SHA-1 hash, full or abbreviated. If `$sha` is in fact *not* a SHA hash, but an arbitrary identifier, then things are are somewhat ambiguous, as the OP never makes clear whether he want to resolve the identifier (as in this answer) or not.

Comment: Sorry if I was no clear, I mean that if it's the SHA of a tag object it will still work, not only for the SHA of a commit object.

Comment: I would suggest editing to add `if git cat-file... >& /dev/null` to avoid the "fatal: Not a valid object name" output to `stderr`

Answer (score 11):

The error code of this command will be 0 if the commit exists, or 1 if not:

```
git rev-parse -q --verify "$sha^{commit}" > /dev/null
```

If you want an easier read, append `&& echo "exists" || echo "doesn't exist"`.

From the `git rev-parse` docs:

> ```
>    --verify
>        Verify that exactly one parameter is provided, and that it can be turned into a raw 20-byte SHA-1 that can be used to access the object database. If so, emit it to the standard output; otherwise, error out.
>
>        If you want to make sure that the output actually names an object in your object database and/or can be used as a specific type of object you require, you can add the ^{type} peeling operator to the parameter. For
>        example, git rev-parse "$VAR^{commit}" will make sure $VAR names an existing object that is a commit-ish (i.e. a commit, or an annotated tag that points at a commit). To make sure that $VAR names an existing object of
>        any type, git rev-parse "$VAR^{object}" can be used.
>
>    -q, --quiet
>        Only meaningful in --verify mode. Do not output an error message if the first argument is not a valid object name; instead exit with non-zero status silently. SHA-1s for valid object names are printed to stdout on
>        success.
> ```

As a bonus, if you don't suppress the output, you can get the full sha.

Comment: This does not work for me, I get the following error: `fatal: Needed a single revision`.

Comment: @caram: That error shows up when you don't use -q, right? Hard to tell what the problem is. It gives the same error when the commit isn't found, when $sha isn't long enough to be unique, and when you've made a syntax error in the parameter.

Comment: @caram thats the error it gives if it can't find it.

Comment: Why not just `git rev--parse $committish` (it errors out if the hash it not found)

Comment: @BlackMantha not sure if I'm misunderstanding you, but `git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD^{commit}` doesn't seem to report an error? so I don't think this distinguishes between commit hashes and things that refer to them

Comment: also as pointed out in another comment, `git rev-parse --verify` seems happy to accept any full SHA hash, even if no commit exists with that hash

Comment: @BenMilwood This command communicates via the exit code. But that was only in the quoted doc, so I edited my answer to make this explicit.

Answer (score 9):

If you are sure that the sha are commits then `cat-file -e` can be used for example:

```
if git cat-file -e $sha 2> /dev/null 
then 
  echo exists 
else 
  echo missing 
fi
```

This is pretty efficient as this is a built-in and doesn't do anything other than checking the sha exists:

```
return !has_sha1_file(sha1);
```

Otherwise if it is uncertain that the sha are commit objects you would need to determine the type as with the other answer using `git cat-file -t`.  This is only slightly less performant as git would have to look at the file information. This isn't as costly as unpacking the whole file.

Comment: `git rev-parse --verify` will only check if the identifier is a valid hash. `git rev-parse --verify 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890` will always return true

Comment: Exactly. I have used this method, i.e. `git rev-parse $sha`, initially, but it turns out it exits with success on any valid hash.

Comment: Quite right, really the top one one is translating the a ref into the sha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e09f1254c54329773904fe25d7c545a1fb4fa920), "[`git --no-lazy-fetch cmd`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2c206fc82abb3ae3d8a5fb5b3c07c1a933007f31/Documentation/git.txt#L182)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---no-lazy-fetch))</sup> allows running cmd while disabling lazy fetching of objects from the promisor remote, which may be handy for debugging (in case of a [partial clone with filter](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2c206fc82abb3ae3d8a5fb5b3c07c1a933007f31/t/t0410-partial-clone.sh#L661-L662)).

So in your case:

```
git --no-lazy-fetch cat-file -e $sha 
# or
GIT_NO_LAZY_FETCH=1 git cat-file -e $sha
```

See [commit e6d5479](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6d5479e7ac301ae8d11daa3d8ef748e891c91c3) (27 Feb 2024), [commit b3806f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3806f7633f69d44a2ade95b92ba21fb59362f4e) (16 Feb 2024), and [commit c784b0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c784b0a5b991cc8ee179b8f3a8fc0b762708947d) (08 Feb 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2c206fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c206fc82abb3ae3d8a5fb5b3c07c1a933007f31), 07 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`git`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c784b0a5b991cc8ee179b8f3a8fc0b762708947d): `--no-lazy-fetch` option

> Sometimes, especially during tests of low level machinery, it is handy to have a way to disable lazy fetching of objects.
> This allows us to say, for example, "[`git cat-file -e`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c784b0a5b991cc8ee179b8f3a8fc0b762708947d/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L50)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file#Documentation/git-cat-file.txt--e))</sup> `<object-name>`, to see if the object is locally available.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c784b0a5b991cc8ee179b8f3a8fc0b762708947d/Documentation/git.txt#L180-L184):

> ### `--no-lazy-fetch`
>
> Do not fetch missing objects from the promisor remote on
> demand.  Useful together with `git cat-file -e <object>` to
> see if the object is locally available.
> This is equivalent to setting the `GIT_NO_LAZY_FETCH`
> environment variable to `1`.

> ### [`git`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6d5479e7ac301ae8d11daa3d8ef748e891c91c3): extend `--no-lazy-fetch` to work across subprocesses

> Modeling after how the `--no-replace-objects` option is made usable across subprocess spawning (e.g., cURL based remote helpers are spawned as a separate process while running "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e6d5479e7ac301ae8d11daa3d8ef748e891c91c3/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>), allow the `--no-lazy-fetch` option to be passed across process boundaries.
>
> Do not model how the value of `GIT_NO_REPLACE_OBJECTS` environment variable is ignored, though.
> Just use the usual `git_env_bool()` to allow "export `GIT_NO_LAZY_FETCH=0"` and "unset `GIT_NO_LAZY_FETCH"` to be equivalents.
>
> Also do not model how the request is not propagated to subprocesses we spawn (e.g. "[`git clone --local`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e6d5479e7ac301ae8d11daa3d8ef748e891c91c3/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L46)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---local))</sup> that spawns a new process to work in the origin repository, while the original one working in the newly created one) by the "`--no-replace-objects`" option, as this "do not lazily fetch from the promisor" is more about a per-request debugging aid, not "this repository's promisor should not be relied upon" property specific to a repository.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e6d5479e7ac301ae8d11daa3d8ef748e891c91c3/Documentation/git.txt#L905-L909):

> ### `GIT_NO_LAZY_FETCH`
>
> Setting this Boolean environment variable to true tells Git
> not to lazily fetch missing objects from the promisor remote
> on demand.

Answer (score 0):

`git rev-list HEAD..$sha` will check if the $sha *relates* to `HEAD`.

`git cat-file commit $sha` will check if the $sha exists in the repository.

So it will depend on your use-case.

One use case that needs the first option, for instance: checking if upstream has new commits

```
# FETCH_HEAD = 2d9dbaa

$ git rev-list main..2d9dbaa
2d9dbaad0aad8e63b99235448c5aa4f82e9b1837
...
fb44705de992b19efd77af6e2f05e4fc1a79b568
$ git rev-list FETCH_HEAD..2d9dbaa
$ git cat-file -e 2d9dbaa && echo exists
exists
```

Using `rev-list` I can validate that `main` does not have revision `2d9dbaa` while `cat-file` would not help (as revision does exist in a different branch).