# warning: refname 'xxx' is ambiguous

Tags: git

I wonder why I get the warning of refname is ambiguous?

Does it mean that there are no more than two branches whose names start with the string? But there is no here.

Thanks.

```
$ git checkout  B03799
warning: refname 'B03799' is ambiguous.
Switched to branch 'B03799'

$ git branch -l
  B03318
  B03318new
  B03318newnew
  B03318newnewQa
  B03336
  B03701
* B03799
  master
  qa
  staging
```

Comment: Do you have any other refs?  (e.g. tags)

Comment: Thanks. How can I find it out if I have any other refs?

Comment: `git show-ref`.

Comment: the string `B03799` only appear once in the output of `git show-ref`.

Comment: I run `git show-ref | less`, and type `/B03799`  to do the search. Or what should I look for instead?

Comment: Maybe you have a commit whose hash begins with `b03799`.

Answer (score 7):

You have *something* in your repo that is also named `B03799`. Most likely a tag (use `git tag` to list tags), branch (see `git branch -a` to include remote tracking branches), or a commit whose SHA begins with b03799 (use i.e. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516021/1615903) to verify). Git has to guess which one you want, but it also gives you a warning so that you know it might have guessed wrong.

You may want to change your branch naming convention so that they don't collide with the hashes, i.e. including at least one character other than 0-9 and a-f.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's an internal Git object whose hash ID begins with `b03799`. Note that in this case, *most* Git commands go directly to the object, but `git checkout` resolves the branch name. Your best bet is to rename the branch, otherwise you have to type in `refs/heads/B03799`  with many Git commands.