# How to find the github repository associated with a heroku app?

Tags: github, heroku

This question is quite simple. I have a heroku app deployed, and I cannot find it's source code.

How can we retrieve the **github repository url** for a given heroku app via either the heroku CLI or by the heroku web interface?

Edit: yes, this has been troubling me for over a year now

#### What I've tried

I have tried [`heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME`](https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku) which copies the repository (from heroku?) to local. After `cd`ing into it, and trying to [get the github remote url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4089452/5783745)

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

but that returns blank. I also tried

```
git remote show origin  
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Are you sure that there _is_ a GitHub repository associated with the app? There might not be. Who initially deployed it?

Comment: @Chris I deployed it, and it was definitely deployed from github repo (I don't know any other way). I just don't know which github repo this app stems from, and don't want to delete it in case there is something important there. I think heroku should state the github url somewhere, that would be an easy solve, but I can't seem to locate it

Comment: So... you deployed it from GitHub, but you don't remember which specific repo you deployed from? You can see the commit hash using [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases). I'm not sure that anything shows the GitHub repo, but try checking there.

Comment: @Chris Yes exactly. This is not hard to envisage if you have hundreds of apps. Heroku's strength is that it makes it trivial to deploy an app (e.g. ~30 seconds from laptop, to git, to heroku). This is great for quickly deploying microservices and the like. Every so often, I clean up unused or necessary apps, which hasn't been a problem until now since most apps have something at their root url. But in one case, it doesn't, and I don't want to delete it until I am sure it's not something important.

Comment: @Chris Running `heroku releases -a myappname` returns expected output (but no mention of the repo). I try `git log -n 1 9643b02d -a myappname` (where the commit is the most recent from the output of the first command), and get `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just tried `heroku slugs:download -a myapp` and get
>
> ```
> Warning: slugs:download is not a heroku command.
> ```

You would need to install the [`heroku/heroku-slugs`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-slugs) plugin first, in order for that command to be recognized.

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs
```

But try first, as you did

```
heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
```

And then `git log -1`: that will give you the SHA1 of the latest commit.

You can then do on GitHub a [Commit search by hash](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-commits#search-by-hash).
Example:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/search?q=hash%3A124a9a0ee1d8f1e15e833aff432fbb3b02632105&type=Commits

---

The [OP stevec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5783745/stevec) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688066/how-to-find-the-github-repository-associated-with-a-heroku-app#comment112181913_63435277) using "[How to clone all repos at once from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32833411/6309)" to handle more than 100 repositories and (critically) download the private ones too (not just public).
That is: write a bash script that clones every repository on my account and somehow searches for a particular SHA.

I suggests a simple `git log -1 SHA`, or;, following "[How to check if the commit exists in a Git repository by its SHA-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654238/6309)":

```
git rev-parse -q --verify "$sha^{commit}" > /dev/null
```

The OP adds:

> I realised your initial solution definitely works (even for private repos).
>
> ```
> heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
> git log -1, 
> https://github.com/search?q=hash%3A<SHA>
> ```

Comment: Thanks! It all makes sense. But after getting the commit SHA and searching for it, I see `We couldn’t find any commits matching ..`. I have tinkered a little to ensure I'm searching all of github, tried the search box with `hash:...` and altering the URL a couple of ways (trying both `:` and `%3A`), but I don't seem to be able to get any results. I will try `git log -2` (and so on) and hopefully one matches. If you have any other ideas they'd be appreciated!

Comment: @stevec was your original repo private? A search would work only on the master branch of public repos.

Comment: I guess it may have been. I am thinking one solution from here could be to write a bash script that clones every repository on my account and somehow searches for a particular SHA. If this goes smoothly I guess it wouldn't take all that long. Do you know of any better/easier way?

Comment: @stevec "somehow searches for a particular SHA.":  a `simple git log <sha>` in each of those cloned repos would be enough.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32833411/) to handle > 100 repositories and (critically) download the private ones too (not just public)

Comment: @stevec Good approach. I have included your comments and a few suggestions in the answer, for more visibility.

Comment: I had extra complications due to some mistakes I made, but I realised your initial solution definitely works (even for private repos). `heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME`, `git log -1`, then visiting `https://github.com/search?q=hash%3A<SHA>` definitely works

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku) on downloading your code. Heroku allows you to clone the git repo from their servers - so as long as you have access to the app in Heroku, you can see the exact code that has been deployed.

Comment: ...[but](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app) "A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub."

Comment: I just tried `heroku slugs:download -a myapp` and get `›   Warning: slugs:download is not a heroku command.`